# Вызов ошибки "jquery.js:1580 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Tags: javascript, html

На странице есть код:

```js
$script = <<<JS
    $( "#select_test" ).change(function() {
        var select = document.getElementById("select_test");
        var value = select.value;
        
        debugger;
        
        $.post(
            "/education/dialogs/add-result-general-test/check",
            {testValue : value , group_id: "$csrf" },
            function(html){
                console.log(html);    
                $("#result-zone").load(html, null);
             },   
                //$.pjax.reload({container : '#result-zone' , timeout : false});,
            //"json",
        ).done(function(html){
                console.log(html);
             },
        );
    });
JS;
```

```html
<br> <div class="form-group" id="result-zone"></div>
```

На сервер посылается запрос и возвращается форма: код с функции console.log()

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 

<label for="nameStudent263" class="col-md-4 control-label">Мария Лопатина</label> <div class="col-sm-8"> <select id="nameStudent263" class="form-control" name="name263"> <option value="">Выберите оценку</option> <option value="Зачёт">Зачёт</option> <option value="Не зачёт">Не зачёт</option> </select> </div> <br> 

<label for="nameStudent281" class="col-md-4 control-label">Алиса Савцова</label> <div class="col-sm-8"> <select id="nameStudent281" class="form-control" name="name281"> <option value="">Выберите оценку</option> <option value="Зачёт">Зачёт</option> <option value="Не зачёт">Не зачёт</option> </select> </div> <br> 

<label for="nameStudent297" class="col-md-4 control-label">Дарья Цысь</label> <div class="col-sm-8"> <select id="nameStudent297" class="form-control" name="name297"> <option value="">Выберите оценку</option> <option value="Зачёт">Зачёт</option> <option value="Не зачёт">Не зачёт</option> </select> </div> <br>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в том, что вместо метода `load` внутри обработчика нужно было использовать [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: т.е. как должно было выглядеть?                 $("#result-zone").html;

Comment: не, `$("#result-zone").html(html, null);`

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. Оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде использован метод [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), который загружает разметку по указанному адресу. Первый параметр должен быть `url`.

Однако в данном случае передается полученный `html`, из-за этого возникает ошибка.

Для непосредственной вставки `html` На страницу нужно использовать метод [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$("#result-zone").html(html, null);
```